# Keep String array not alphabetical sorted

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I need to create a Navigation Drawer with Expandable List View, so I wrote this code to create my menu:

```
            Map<String, List<String>> lstChild;
            List<String> lstTitle;

            List<String> title = Arrays.asList("Social", "Collaborazione", "Web", "Squadre");
            List<String> childSquadre = Arrays.asList("U13", "U16", "U18");
            List<String> childSocial = Arrays.asList("FB", "Instagram", "Linkedin");

            lstChild = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
            lstChild.put(title.get(0), childSquadre);
            lstChild.put(title.get(1), childSocial);

            lstTitle = new ArrayList<String>(lstChild.keySet());
```

The final lstTitle is sort by alphabetical order, even if I add each element on the order that I want, that is: Social, Collaborazione, Web, Squadre.

So, how do I sort the lstTitle arraylist not alphabetical?

Comment: The `keySet()`-method returns the keys in ascending order. Which is alphabetical for Strings. So it's doing exactly what is expected. If you want another behavior, don't use the `keySet()` method.

Comment: Where is `lstChild` used?

Comment: @Eselfar it is used in the last row

Comment: Yeah but I guess it's used later on too?

Comment: Nope. Only into this part of code

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to create a TreeMap then? Just use `title` as `lstTitle`

Comment: For what? I don't understand. My final target is to create an expandle menu. So I create a TreeMap to merge all array lists

Comment: I asked where is `lstChild` used and you replied `only into this part of code`. In the code you've provided, `lstChild` is not really used, as the final result in `lstTitle` is the same as if had done `lstTitle = new ArrayList<>(title);`

Comment: Mmm I need to try it. I'll let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally use:

```
lstChild = new LinkedHashMap <String, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lstChild = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
```

TreeMap class implements Map interface similar to HashMap class.

The main difference between them is that HashMap is an unordered collection while TreeMap is sorted in the ascending order of its keys.

So replace your `TreeMap` with `HashMap`

Comment: The issue is indeed the TreeMap but an HashMap is neither a solution: `This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.` [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap)

Comment: If I use a HashMap I get the sort that I want. But @Eselfar what do you advise to do?

Comment: I dont think what @Eselfar said is totally correct, refer this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-treemap-hashmap-linkedhashmap-java/

Comment: Which part of the page you linked contradict what I said? According to your document it's better to use a `LinkedHashMap` as "the keys are ordered by their insertion order". I agree

Comment: Thanks @Eselfar a LinkedHashMap it's the better solution